# How to get relative path, not full path in map files with Closure Controller? `

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I'm using **Google Closure Compiler** to minify my JS scripts:  https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_app?hl=en

The command I'm using is:

```
java -jar /home/user/compiler/compiler.jar --js $File::Find::name --create_source_map $File::Find::name.map --source_map_format=V3 --compilation_level=WHITESPACE_ONLY --js_output_file $minified --charset=Windows-1251 --output_wrapper '%output%\n//# sourceMappingURL=output.js.map'
```

Thats fine, apart from one thing - the **.js.map** file has the *FULL* path for the file, not the relative one:

```
"version":3,
"file":"/home/user/public_html/new_design/common37.min.js",
"lineCount":375,
....
```

I assume I can change this in the invocation of the compiler.jar script? Otherwise, I guess I will have to add some more code into my script (not something I want to do, if its possible "out of the box")

**EDIT:** I've done a little bit of a dirty hack in my Perl script:

```
        # now open the map file one, and edit it to remove the full path.. needs to be relative
        my $contents = File::Slurp::read_file("/home/user/public_html/$tmp.map");
        $contents =~ s|/home/user/public_html||g;
        File::Slurp::write_file("/home/user/public_html/$tmp.map",$contents);
```

That gets rid of the path info correctly. I've prefer if there were an option to use relative urls in the *.map* file (compared to the full path it currently puts in)

Thanks!

Comment: You might be able to do this with the `--source_map_location_mapping` flag. I haven't tried it myself though.

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth - thanks - I can't seem to get it working though :( `java -jar /home/user/compiler/compiler.jar --js /home/user/public_html/new_design/addmodify.js --create_source_map /home/user/public_html/new_design/addmodify.js.map --source_map_format=V3 --compilation_level=WHITESPACE_ONLY --js_output_file /home/user/public_html/new_design/addmodify.min.js --source_map_location_mapping=/ --charset=Windows-1251 --output_wrapper '%output%\n//# sourceMappingURL=/home/user/public_html/new_design/addmodifytest.min.map'` - gives  Bad value for --source_map_location_mapping (duplicate key): [/]

Comment: It should be formatted like: `--source_map_location_mapping=/filesystem/src/root|relative/source/root`

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth - aaaahhh that was it! Could you please add that as the answer, so I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify sourcemap location transformations by using the `--source_map_location_mapping` flag. The flag expects a value formatted as:

```
--source_map_location_mapping=/filesystem/src/root|relative/source/root
```